# How to config Vue 2 application on IIS server?

Tags: iis-7, vuejs2, windows-server-2008, vue-router

I need help with config IIS server and Vue 2 application, I just installed `vue 2 application` with production build on `Windows IIS 7 server`, and all work fine, only one thing is not working: 
When I try to open any page with link "`example mysite.com/somepage`" which written in vue-router i see `404 error`, but if I click on menu link work fine, if you type just main url mysite.com it will open, but any another routes not working!

I think I need to setting my httpRedirect or something like this!

Comment: foo.com/#/example ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your information I'm assuming you're using the `history` mode, here's the one I've been using, and you can reference on [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The Link is broken. Please fix it

Comment: what are the survey paths?

Answer (score 11):

As noted in the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), in order to use history mode, you need to do the following:

1. Install IIS UrlRewrite.
2. Drop a web.config file into the root of the project. See the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) for an example web.config file.

Comment: The links are broken. Please fix it or remove the answer.

Comment: Vue changed the path in their documentation. I updated the links accordingly.