# Getting error ( POST 500 Internal Server Error) when running Full-Stack Web application in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, express

I have developed a full-stack application with Vue 2, Node , Express and Postgres.
I could deploy the application to Azure , and the system coming up, but when I try to do register user with Register page that I have created , I get " POST … 500 (Internal Server Error) ", **as I have tried with Postman , there is no issue in saving user data with same post controller ** .

Notice that I have set BaseURL to ‘’ in Api.js ( Client ):

```
import axios from ‘axios’
import store from ‘@/store/store’
export default () => {
   return axios.create({
      baseURL: ‘’,
      headers: {
           Authorization: Bearer ${store.state.token}
      }
   })
}
```

this is Register controller in /Controller folder :
//Registering user

```
async register(req, res) {
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
     try {
         const user = await User.create(
         Object.assign(req.body, { password: hash })
      );
   const userJson = user.toJSON();
   res.send({
          user: userJson,
          token: jwtSignUser(userJson),
         });
  } catch (err) {
     res.status(500).send({
     error: There is error in registering: ${err},
 });
 }
},
```

I have added the following web.config file in dist folder, but it doesn't resolve the issue :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" /> 
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      
      <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
    </rewrite>
     
      <httpErrors>     
          <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />                
          <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="/survey/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />                
          <error statusCode="500" path="/survey/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      </httpErrors>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Could you please let me know how I could resolve the issue .

Comment: If your project works fine in local, the error must be in web.config.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778566/how-to-config-vue-2-application-on-iis-server/45786177

Comment: it works in local , I have tried web.config and put in root in dist folder , also I tried and placed the web.config in root , but I have same issue

Comment: If you copy the content of dist folder to wwwroot, you don’t need web.config file.

Comment: The structure of wwwroot like your local, not the content of dist, will need web.config.

Comment: @JasonPan , I have done as you suggested , same issue

Comment: If possible, can you create a sample project without any sensitive info for me, I can test in my side.

Comment: Put the `web.config` to the root folder of your project. See the node sample: https://github.com/microsoft/project-nodejs-express-webapp